# Any New Column is Null value in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am adding a new column to exiting database table with values, but when I used the entity framework model, the column data value return Null, however its has a real value in database.

How solve this problem?

Comment: add tabe definition, add class definition, add query, show problem place...

Comment: @MohammadDiab You are using LINQ or Stored Procedure for data retrieval?

Comment: I'm currently trying to grow tomatoes in my garden. I've planted tomato seeds. However, nothing grows. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You should read [ask].

Comment: I think I understand and will try to clarify: Mohammad has an existing application that uses EF and which is working fine. Now, after having added a column to a table and having updated the model, whenever data is retrieved, the value of the newly added field is always null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using **LINQ** for data retrieval:

Double click and open edmx -> right click and select update from database -> select refresh tab and select your table and click ok.

The above will update your dbcontext file.

[image]

[image]

If you are using stored procedure, you will have to update the complex type of your stored procedure

Comment: thanks so much for your reply, I did the update model from database the fields is mapping correct and the model updated but when I used the Entity_Object.TableName.ToList(); the rows comes correctly but the new column value comes NULL

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation for your problem is that you did not COMMIT the changes you made to the database. Not the changes to the schema but the table updates. EF is returning NULL values because you did not commit your changes so the actual field values are ... NULL !